# How to validate only certain instances of a rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

What is wrong with my model that I can't see the `#black?` method?

Error:

> undefined method `black?' for Car:Class

Car Modal

```
  # frozen_string_literal: true

  class Cars < Base

    if black?
      validates :style, presence: true
    end

    private

    def black?
     color_options.include?("black")
    end

  end
```

If I do...

```
validates :style, presence: true, if: :seller?
```

The code works, but I plan on adding many more validations in the if statement block, so it would be nice to get the if statement block (if end) working.

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `black?` on the class, not on an instance of the class. At the point that your `if black?` code is called, `self` evaluates to `Cars`! It wouldn't make any sense to call `Cars.black?` - you want to know if a single instance of the car is black!

It is good practice to wrap all your various validation conditions into a single predicate which you then reference with the `:if` syntax.

For example, if you had a complex set of conditions, you might set up a validator:

```
class Cars
  validates :style, presence: true, if: :validate_style?

  private

  def validate_style?
    color_options.include?("black") ||
      wheel_options.include?("premium") ||
      Time.now.wday == 3
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, mistated, I meant , I needed to add many more validations in the if statement block.

Comment: You can use a proc as empr mentioned, or your validation method can include whatever logic you want to return true/false.

Comment: So the main issue as I see it is that I needed self.black?, to refer to the instance

Comment: Right. You need to be calling `black?` in an instance context (ie, from within an instance method), rather than a class context. When you're _defining_ your validation line, you're in a class context.

Comment: What if I have multiple valdiations related to one conditonal?  How do  I wrap them in an if block?

Comment: You would typically guard each of them with an `if:` option.